# Gaussian Minimizes Uncertainty - Statement Qualification

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

On the last page of [this paper](http://people.physics.tamu.edu/herschbach/commuting%20observables%20and%20simultaneous%20eigenfunctions.pdf), the following statements are made (I'll jump right to around the point of interest):

> **Example:** Consider $A=p_x$, $B=x$.
>
> Then  $$\langle A\rangle=\langle B\rangle=0;\,\,\,\Delta A=\sqrt{p_x^2},\,\,\,\Delta B=\sqrt{x^2}$$
>
> $$[x,p]=i\hbar\implies C=\hbar=\langle C\rangle$$
>
> $$\Delta p_x \Delta x \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$$
>
> For the minimum uncertainty state we have,
>
> $$p_x\psi = \frac{i\hbar}{2(\Delta x)^2}x\psi \tag{1}$$
>
> With $p_x=i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}$, the solution to the differential equation gives
>
> $$\psi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2\pi(\Delta x)^2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2(\Delta x)^2}}$$

It's clear that notation is being abused like Matilda, but putting that aside I can't see where equation $(1)$ came from.

This looks like a good proof that Gaussians make HUP into an equality, so I would very much appreciate if you could help point me in the right direction.

Comment: Taking the norm of (1),  $\langle \psi p |p \psi\rangle=(\Delta p)^2=...$, do you observe it saturates the inequality above it?